# Difficulty parsing JSON 3 levels deep

Tags: react-native

React native is having difficulties parsing JSON three levels deep. The object is structured like so:

```
  data: {
    post: {
      user1: {
        name: "user name"
      }
    }
  }
```

data.post.user1 works fine and returns an object; however, when I try to get the name parameter react-native throws the following error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.post.user1.name')
```

Is this a known issue? I am getting data from response.json in a fetch call. EDIT: Object.keys(data.post.user1) returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First, declare it in a variable and then make an object :

```
const data = {
    date:{
    post: {
    user1: {
     name: "user name"
      }
    }}}
```

Get the value like this :

```
<Text>{data.date.post.user1.name}</Text>
```